# ¿Como puedo realizar un pedido de una frase a un usuario correctamente?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Me piden que le pida a un usuario un numero que se encuentre entre 1 y 1000 y luego se imprima la frase “Die Bart Die” la cantidad de veces que el usuario lo solocito en el rango. Si el usuario ingresa un numero fuera del rango, se le debe pedír nuevamente que ingrese valores dentro del rango.

Mi duda es la siguiente ¿porque no funciona el if(numero<1)?, cada vez que le ingreso un valor negativo automaticamente termina el programa, sin realizar la funcion que le pido que haga.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int datos(){
int numero;
printf("\nIngrese un numero que este en el rango de 1 a 1000: ");
 scanf("%d", &numero);
int numero2[sizeof numero];

for(int i=0; i<numero; i++){
    printf("die bart die\n", numero2[i]);
}
}
int main(){
 int numero;
 
 printf("Ingrese un numero que este en el rango de 1 a 1000: ");
  scanf("%d", &numero);
 int numero2[sizeof numero];

 for(int i=0; i<numero; i++){
  if(numero>1000){
    printf("\nError vuelva a ingresa los datos solicitados\n");
    datos();
    return 0;
 }if(numero<1){
    printf("\nError vuelva a ingresa los datos solicitados\n");
    datos();
    return 0;
 }else{ 
  printf("die bart die\n", numero2[i]);
 }
 }

 Al codigo le falta esa correcion y si me pueden ayudar un poco con la sintaxis se lo 
 agradeceria.
```

Comment: No lo comparto como respuesta por que no estoy del todo seguro pero, es mucho mas sencillo si usas una condicional en conjunto es decir if(numero<100 && numero > 1000){ printf("\nError vuelva a ingresa los datos solicitados\n"); }
else{printf("die bart die\n", numero2[i]); }

Comment: La verificación la debes hacer fuera del ciclón. Solo me pregunto por qué tienes dos arreglos con más de un millón de elementos. Tómate un momento para pensar la lógica del programa.

Comment: Por qué la función datos vuelve a pedir que ingrese un número?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado remarco dos problemas:

1- Ud pregunta por el valor de numero, luego el bucle intenta iterar desde 0 hasta numero, si numero es menor que 0 nada sera iterado

2- La entrada de numero debe estar en un buble que repita la pregunta a hasta que a la respuesta sea válida de 1 a 1000

Abajo pego un link con el programa funcionando:

https://tio.run/##ZZAxU8MwDIV3/4p34cIl10LTjiR0Z2YEBmOrqe4SuXUSGGh/e3ASlwUNsi1Ln9@zeaiNGcc7FtMMllB1vWX3eNwrxdKj1SxZrn4UQkwFGVryrlRzwbp5WW6nOPnQc8iSF6k9dYRB4gDOA4G6PiQBNfBaaofw3hYa26IonpDk5R@nM1oCJrXJGvcLId5e5/x95IayLLIrbHNcLrid9zMxDxOLzIPz2aSd8YyiBFfRBHi1yqODfxYsEz617zFtUvsuQcpNCTYbvBJ0MBlcpBYn7TW@yKPR4J68NuxkjY4hDuEfzgOTp7mDGm5ZtI@wN/6Ivq5qHHfFLw

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo había resuelto pero me diste una idea para achicar el código mucho más.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gracias a lo gente que me ayudó.
El nuevo código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(){
      int numero;
      int numero2[0];

  printf("Ingrese un numero que este en el rango de 1 a 1000: ");
  scanf("%d", &numero);

  while((numero < 1) || (numero > 1000)){
   printf("\nError vuelva a ingresa los datos solicitados\n\n");
    main();
     return 0;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<numero; i++){
    printf("die bart die\n", numero2[i]);
  }
  }
```